# Zurb Foundation small columns do not flow

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm working with Zurb Foundation 4.3 and am having trouble wrapping my head around Zurb's small and large column classes.  In the code sample below using just large classes for columns, the 2nd column will get repositioned below the first column when the UI width changes.  This is nice because it keeps the UI content clean

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="large-8 columns rounded">
            Bubbles
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 columns rounded">
            Yadda Yadda Yadda
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, if I add small classes to the columns, the 2nd column doesn't get repositioned resulting in a messy UI.

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="small-4 large-8 columns rounded">
            Bubbles
        </div>
        <div class="small-8 large-4 columns rounded">
            Yadda Yadda Yadda
        </div>
    </div>
```

I like the ability to be able to change the column widths of the content as the overall page changes widths.  However, as I drag the page from wide to narrow, the content doesn't reposition if I use the small classes.  What am I missing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The small classes control the widths of your columns on small screens, without specifying small classes, columns default to small-12 or 100% width on small screens which is why you see them stack vertically.

In your second example, the first column to second columns ratio will be 1:2 for small screens instead the 2:1 on medium screens. The columns positioned next to each other in the same order but their sizes are swapped.
This should be what you are seeing.

If you wish to have them stack vertically like in the first example but swap the order of columns, use

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 push-8 columns rounded">
        Yadda Yadda Yadda
    </div>
    <div class="large-8 pull-4 columns rounded">
        Bubbles
    </div>
</div>
```

If this is not what you wish to achieve I'll help you specify another solution

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I've tried adding push/pull classes and it swaps the order of the divs.  I simply need to have yadda yadda column on left and bubbles on right except when the width of the page gets to a point where it pushes bubbles below yadda yadda. I like the way large handles it by pushing the secnd column under the first, but this functionality goes away when the small-xx classes are added.  Small alters the experience, so I'm clearly not understanding how this works.  I don't see the need for push/pull when it alters the order of the columns.

Comment: If you're fine with yadda yadda at top/left and bubbles right/bottom we don't need push/pull as you said. If you want the small screen view to have full widths we don't even need small classes. If you want the small screen view to have specified widths that's where the small classes come in. As long as they sum up to more than 12 (for 12 col grid) it will overflow to next row. So that's why when you use small-8 small-4 it's still on the same row. If you used small-12 small-4 yadda yadda will have full width while bubbles half width below but aligned right (last child).

Comment: i'm quite curious, what is it about example 1 in your post that is not what you wanted?